# Symbian c++ - how to put own static lib

Tags: c++, static, symbian

I'm using carbide c++. What to put in .mmp file to link some static library in path: camerawrapper\epoc32\release\armv5\lib from root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
STATICLIBRARY foo.lib
```

assuming your EPOCROOT/SDK root is `camerawrapper`, you are building for the armv5 target and there's such a static library built with `TARGETTYPE lib`, not e.g. a static interface DLL.